# Why was my question closed as "Not a Real Question"?

Tags: support, closed-questions, close-reasons, reopen-closed

[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077910/how-to-make-a-linkedin-application) asked about the application on LinkedIn profile which should be shown separately in User's Profile like the applications listed [here](http://www.linkedin.com/static?key=application_directory). The question is simple, but still it was downvoted and closed as "Not a real question".

I didn't get any comment on how to improve it. The only answer which I got just posted links of LinkedIn blogs, which do not answer my question, and it was deleted too. The comment on the question just linked to the api, which I already visited and found nothing there.

The API is not my answer, my answer is where's the link or topic which tells me about those kind of LinkedIn Application. Why does no one seem to understand this?

Comment: Do you also consider the questions "How do I make a Form in C#?", "How do I write a GUI application in Java" and "How can I write a Facebook application which does exactly the same like this application?" good questions? If yes, I have bad news for you...99% of people don't. They're too broad, hardly answerable or not really practical to answer.

Comment: @GardenGnobobby The problem is I can't find how can I make those kind of application, and there's nothing on LinkedIn's Dev site, I already checked and searched enough.

Comment: As Bart said, that doesn't make it more On-Topic or suitable for Stack Overflow.

Comment: So is there any modification or edit I can make on the question which can make it on-topic? I just want any official link for tutorial on such kind of application. I thought may be I couldn't find but someone must have found that.

Comment: You've come to talk with the wrong guy. I've the strict opinion that SE is not a search engine, even if your own Search Fu fails you (I'd have some of those questions myself)...and I don't see any way to make that question fitting.

Comment: I don't think there is. You're simply not at a stage yet in your development, where the question would be a good fit. Perhaps (but I really have no idea) there is an appropriate chat on SO where you could inquire about your problem. Or maybe LinkedIN itself has a developer forum?

Comment: As a matter of fact Chat ***might*** work for that...and that's a big ***MIGHT***...even bigger then on a 23" screen with 640x480 resolution with a font-size of 72!

Comment: Ok, I got my answer through one of my friend who saw my question. I posted it as a comment on original question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You ask

> Can you provide me any help, tutorial or guide for this and what
>   technology do I need to use to make them?

Such a question is simply not a good fit for Stack Overflow for a variety of reasons.

The major problem here is that it's simply too broad and there is no practical issue you face at the moment. You should ideally do a majority of the research by yourself. Once you start to implement your application and are stuck on a practical problem, SO would be a good fit for your question.

Comment: I researched on my own, I checked on SO and checked LinkedIn's Dev site. I need to know from where to start, since until I know where to start from, I can't make the application.

Comment: That doesn't make SO the right podium for your question. I know that might sound annoying, but questions like that are not a good fit. I'm not saying you did nothing to solve your problems, but you're apparently not at a stage where you can ask a question fit for SO.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps people *do* understand, but there simply is no answer.

Or perhaps people do understand, but you haven't shown any indication of real effort that you made. What have you tried?

Or perhaps the original version of the question (before you edited) really was too vague, like the message in the "closed" box says. In that case, flag the question and ask for it to be reopened.

Comment: So if people don't have any answer, they'll vote it to close or downvote? I generally don't have answer on most of the questions, should I vote it to close? I agree with your third point that the question was too broad, but I just asked about a starting step, nothing else.